# integral operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

I have to find the norm of the Volterra integral operator, but I don't know if I did this correct or not. Can anyone help?
$$A:(C[0,1],\mathbb{R})\rightarrow (C[0,1],\mathbb{R})$$
where,
$$(A\phi)(x)=\int_0^x f(y)dy$$
My solution:
\begin{align*}
\|A\|&=\sup{\frac{|(A\phi)(x)|}{\|\phi\|_{\infty}} \text{ s.t. } \phi \in (C[0,1],\mathbb{R}), \phi \neq 0 }\\
&=\sup{|(A\phi)(x)|}=\sup{|\int_0^x \varphi(y)dy|, \|\varphi\|_{\infty}=1}\\
&=\sup(x)
\end{align*}

Comment: What is the connection between $f$ and $\varphi $ ? Moreover, a norm that depend on $x$ is rather change. Finally, a quick check on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra_operator#Further_reading) would have give you the answer.

Comment: how can i bound the right handside if i use norm of x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some good work here, but there are mistakes. The first is that you'll have to use inequality signs, since you brought the absolute values in and then supped out the $\varphi$. Also, you are taking the sup over $x$ and $x\in [0,1]$, so that last sup is actually $1$. You should also be clarifying that you're taking the sup in both $x$ and $\varphi$.

Here's your work with these fixes implemented: for any $x\in [0,1]$ and $\varphi\in C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ with $\|\varphi\|_\infty=1,$ we have the chain of inequalities
$$|(A\varphi)(x)|=\left|\int\limits_0^x \varphi(y)\, dy\right|\leq \int\limits_0^x |\varphi(y)|\, dy\leq \int\limits_0^1 |\varphi(y)|\, dy\leq \sup_{x\in [0,1]}|\varphi(x)|\int\limits_0^1\, dy=1.$$  Since the left-hand side is independent of both $x$ and $\varphi$, we can take sups over both of them and get that $$A=\sup_{\|\varphi\|_\infty=1}\|A\varphi\|_{\infty}\leq 1.$$ On the other hand, if we take $\varphi(x)=1,$ then $\|A\varphi\|_{\infty}=1$, and thus $$\|A\|=1.$$